# Debug @media - tools or how to?

Tags: media

Does anyone know of a firebug like debug tool that will notify user of which @media tag they are currently viewing in?

It would clear up any confusion as to where user should be debugging in the code.

Using the latest Bootstrap (as of today).

Secondly this brings me to the main issue, when the screen size changes elements shift on the screen as expected, however 1 div shifts out in the wrong direction when the screen changes. Observing firebug, no html/css code changes.

So this must be JS? either way where to begin tracking the fault?

Comment: Chrome dev tools automatically brings up used styles to the top within the elements tab. Alternatively you can take a look at the computed styles also located in the elements tab.

Comment: Can see the html/css already, it's difficult to see which media query is being shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dummy element for each selector that you can then inspect using JavaScript and examine its value.

For example:

```
<div id="media-version"></div>

#media-version {
  content:"Full Width";
  display:none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px){
  #media-version {
    content:"520-699 width";
    display:none;
  }
}


alert($('#version').css('content'))
```

You'd have to change the content within each media query.

Comment: i would use console, but yeah that's an option, i am resorting to using a ruler "measureit" for firefox and just dragging it everytime.